# change color on image slowly

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi every one i have a little problem,
before i start i have to say my english is bad sorry.
I made a table with 2 pictures, in it that i want when some one hover on images the color will be change (still picture are visible) by the opacity order, i did it with this code:

```
span.rollover {
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    background: url(images/moreProcuts.png) center center no-repeat #9b1b24;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 170px;
    width: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
span.rollover:hover {
    opacity: .6;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
}
```

But now i want to change the color on pictures slowly, is there any way to do that with javascript or css?.
Thanks!

there is a link of my work to show it works:
http://uupload.ir/files/ptu8_untitled.png

Comment: Could you also show the relevant HTML you're using? Ideally with some images (that are available on the Internet) to show the code 'working'?

Comment: http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/ - use this constructor, to create the animation. As slow as you want.

Comment: @lonDen thanks man that really works and its helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CSS transition:

```
span.rollover {
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

span.rollover:hover {
      opacity: 0.6;
      transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

You can add `-webkit` prefixes to iOS compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @lonDen i changed my  to this:

```
<style>
span.rollover
{
-webkit-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.995);
-moz-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.995);
-o-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.995);
transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.995); /* custom */
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.995);
-moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.995);
-o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.995);
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.995); /* custom */
background: url(images/moreProcuts.png) center center no-repeat #9b1b24;
cursor: pointer;
height: 170px;
width: 250px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
opacity: 0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
span.rollover:hover
{
opacity: .6;
filter: alpha(opacity=60);
-webkit-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.995);
-moz-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.995);
-o-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.995);
transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.995); /* custom */
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.995);
-moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.995);
-o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.995);
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.995); /* custom */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;} <style/>
```

and it works perfectly